# Store an array of UIViews in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview, store, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to add an array of uiviews to NSDefault but it doesn't seem to be keep the array. Does any one know why? I also tried to store each view in nsvalue before storing it in nsdefault which still didn't work.

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:myView], nil]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:arr forKey:@"myKey"];

NSArray *resultArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

and resultArray is nil!

Thanks

the reason why I'm trying to do this is because these are the header views of my uitableview. Since it takes time to create them I wanted to create them only once and store them for future access.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  This is not what NSUserDefaults was designed for.  If you describe what you are trying to accomplish perhaps StackOverflow can give you a better method.

Comment: In that case how about converting these UIViews to UIImages and storing in document folder so that next time you can just add it in an imageView. I am not sure if you should be using NSUserDefaults for storing UIViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do that? It is definitely better to store an array of models to the data base or some file and recreate views from them when needed.

Comment: I figured the reason why it takes so much time to load the my uiview headers was because of the image that they had to load from the server each time. so I only stored those images into nsdata and stored those on nsuserdefault. so now when i want to access them again it doesn't have to load the images from the server so it creates the header views almost instantly now.

Comment: @Mona You should store the images to a file, not in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Mona `NSUserDefaults` is just for small user settings, things like images, models or some other data have to be stored either in db or in files. In your case it is better to save images to files, and i recommend you to use [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it does everything for you (memcache and disk cache) and it is very simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for NSUserDefaults:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings Programming Guide.

If you want to put a UIView (why?) in NSUserDefaults, you need to archive it first into an NSData object.

But you need to ask yourself why you want to put a view in NSUserDefaults. You should only be putting bits of data in NSUserDefaults. Views display data. It's easy to redisplay a view once you have the data back. Consider just putting some needed data in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: is it possible to store uiview in nsdata?

Comment: I wouldn't have told you that you need to archive the view into an NSData object if it wasn't possible. You need to use an NSKeyedArchiver to do it. But again, this is a really bad way of doing things. This is not the purpose of NSUserDefaults. If you really insist on archiving the view, at least store it in a file and not in NSUserDefaults. How long does it actually take to create these views? Do you think recreating them from an archive will be much faster?

Comment: Having tested this recently, NSKeyedArchiver does not guarantee the that the data generated for a view will be unarchived in the exact state that it was left.  I tried attempting this using some drawing code and some gif Imageviews and it did not unarchive properly

Answer (score 1):

A ha!  You are not the first person to face this issue.  I've not had this type of issue myself but, in the link below, is a blog with code that allows you to cache and re-use your views.  Then you would only need to re-create the views when you launch.  Example code:

[Cache UIViews for re-use in tableview](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2010/02/uiviews-cache-for-reuse/)